# Using results of a match to create a win/loss record

Tags: r

If I have data.frame comprising of a date and a result (W or L), how can I use the result to create a record of results? For example, if I have:

```
df
        date     Result
# 1  2015-04-12    W
# 2  2015-04-10    W
# 3  2015-04-09    W
# 4  2015-04-08    W
# 5  2015-04-08    L
# 6  2015-04-07    W
# 7  2015-04-06    L
```

How can I get something like:

```
df
        date     Result   Wins   Losses
# 1  2015-04-12    W       5        2
# 2  2015-04-10    W       4        2
# 3  2015-04-09    W       3        2
# 4  2015-04-08    W       2        2
# 5  2015-04-08    L       1        2
# 6  2015-04-07    W       1        1
# 7  2015-04-06    L       0        1
```

All of the "solutions" I have come up with just add a 1 to each column depending on win or loss. For example:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  if(df$Result[i] == "W") {
    df$Wins[i] <- + 1
  }
  if(df$Result[i] == "L") {
     df$Losses[i] <- + 1
  }
}
```

Thank you. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df$Wins <- rev(cumsum(rev(ifelse(df$Result=="W",1,0))))
df$Losses <- rev(cumsum(rev(ifelse(df$Result=="L",1,0))))
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thanks so much, I appreciate it!